# Duvida sobre submit e jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Asp.Net MVC e estou tendo um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. Tenho um formulário com 2 botoes `submit`, e quando faço o `submit` quero pegar o nome do botão ao qual eu cliquei pelo `id` e assim alterar um `input text` do formulario. O problema é que antes de pegar o nome desse botão o formulário é todo enviado e não consigo pegar o nome desse botão para alterar o valor do `input text`. Logo após o formulário ser submetido, eu tento enviar novamente e enfim consigo pegar o `id` do botão e alterar o valor do `input text`.

Minha dúvida é: Pq quando faço o primeiro submit, ele envia todo o formulário e não pega o id do botão e soh consigo fazer isso depois do processamento ?

Estou tentando fazer assim.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#addPropriedade').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#gravarPublicar').click(function () {
            $('#status').val("1");
        });
        $('#gravar').click(function () {
            $('#status').val("0");
        });
        var dados = new FormData($('#addPropriedade').get(0));



        $("#errorMessage").hide();
        var loading = $("#div_loading");
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            loading.show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            loading.hide();
        });

        $.ajax({
            accepts: { json: 'application/json' },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Propriedade/addAjax",
            data: dados,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var status = data["status"];
                var msg = data["msg"];
                if (status === "1") {
                    $('#addPropriedade').trigger("reset");
                    $("#errorMessage").html(msg);
                    $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-success");
                    //window.location.replace("/Empresa/view");                    
                } else {
                    $("#errorMessage").html(msg);
                    $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-danger");
                }
                $("#errorMessage").show()
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                $("#errorMessage").html("Erro tentando cadastrar");
                $("#errorMessage").prop("class", "alert-danger");
                $("#errorMessage").show()
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Form**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addPropriedade", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <!--Alterar o valor no submit -->
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.status);

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Gravar e Publicar" id="gravarPublicar" name="gravarPublicar" />
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Gravar" id="gravar" name="gravar"/>
    }
```

Comment: Você "não pode" ter 2 botões submit em um formulário, poder pode, mas a especificação é que um form tenha um botão submit que é o botão que envia o formulário.

Acredito que você precisa substituí-los por um input do tipo "button", e após capturar o click deles e pegar os ids, realizar o submit do formulário `$(form).submit()`

Comment: @gabrieloliveira consegui resolver com os 2 submit. Muito simples aliás, retirei o `$(document).ready(function(){})` do JQuery e funcionou blzinha. Obrigado. !

Comment: @FernandoPaiva os eventos `Click` estão dentro do `$(document).ready()`